# Космос и κοσμος

Tags: заимствования

Каким образом грецизм [космос](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81&tbm=isch) мог приобрести в русском языке своё текущее значение (всё то, что вне планеты земля), тогда как в языке-источнике [κοσμος](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%83%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%82) - это с точностью до наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

С точностью до наоборот - это всё, что составляет недра Земли, чего отнюдь не наблюдается.

Кόσμος есть Вселенная, смотрим:

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F)

**ВСЕЛЕННАЯ**

> 1. [как термин - с прописной буквы] Вся система мироздания, весь мир. Строение Вселенной. Тайны Вселенной.

Во всю систему мироздания попадает, среди прочего, Земля,

так что никакого противоречия.

---

Довесок - как **менялось толкование понятия**.

["Космос" по-гречески - это порядок, устройство, стройность (вообще, нечто упорядоченное).](http://www.gctc.ru/print.php?id=277)

> Философы Древней Греции понимали под словом "космос" Мироздание,
>   рассматривая его как упорядоченную гармоничную систему.
>
> В понятие "космос" сначала включали не только мир небесных светил, но
>   и все, с чем мы сталкиваемся на поверхности Земли.
>
> Иногда под космосом понимали только планетную систему, окружающую
>   Солнце. В современном словоупотреблении в связи с этим остался термин
>   "космогония", которым обычно обозначают науку о происхождении
>   Солнечной системы, а не всей Вселенной в целом.
>
> Чаще под космосом понимают Вселенную, рассматриваемую как нечто
>   единое, подчиняющееся общим законам. Отсюда происходит название
>   космологии - науки, пытающейся найти законы строения и развития
>   Вселенной как целого. Таким образом, в названиях "космогония" и
>   "космология" космос понимается в разном смысле.
>
> С начала космической эры (с 1957 г., когда в СССР был запущен первый
>   спутник) слово "космос" приобрело еще одно значение, связанное с
>   осуществлением давнишней мечты человечества о космических полетах. В
>   таких терминах, как "космический полет" или "космонавтика", космос
>   противопоставляется Земле.
>
> В современном понимании космос есть все находящееся за пределами Земли
>   и ее атмосферы. Иногда говорят "космическое пространство"; в странах,
>   пользующихся английским языком - "внешнее пространство" (outer space)
>   или даже просто "пространство" (space).